# Let $R$ be a commutative ring with cardinality greater than $2$. If for every $r \in R$ there exists $a$ s.t $r=2rar$ show that $R$ forms a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with cardinality greater than $2$. If for every $r \in R$ there exists non-zero $a$ such that $r=2rar$ show that $R$ forms a field.

I think I need to show that for $r \in R$ there exists $r^{-1} \in R$ such that $r^{-1}r=1$.

So picking $r \in R$ I have that $r=2rar = rrar$ for some non-zero $a \in R$.What kind of operations I could do to $r$ to get to the identity? I couldn't find any theorems except that if I show that the only ideals of $R$ are $0$ and $R$, then $R$ would be a field, but I'm not sure how I would approach this.

If I assume that $I$ is an ideal of $R$, then $(I,+)$ is a subgroup of $(R,+)$ and therefore it's closed under addition, contains $0$ and for every $x \in I$, there exists $-x$ such that $-x+x=0$. None of these seem to help to show that $I$ must be $0$ or $R$.

Comment: $2rar = rrar$ - why?

Answer (score 1):

The proposition is false. Let $R$ be any commutative von Neumann regular algebra in which $2$ is a unit, and which isn't a field.

For example, one could select a field $F$ not of characteristic $2$, and then form $R=\prod_{i\in I} F$ where $I$ is some index set with more than one element.

Since $R$ is von Neumann regular, for every $r$ there exists a $b$ such that $r=rbr$. Of course, $b$ must be nonzero if $r$ is.

Since $2$ is a unit, $r=rbr=2rar$ where $a=b/2$.  But $R$ is NOT a field.

Comment: Don't I have that since $r=2rar \implies 2ra = e$ and since $R$ is commutative $2a$ is the inverse of $r$?

Comment: Well, just try it out.  Let $R=F_3\times F_3$ where $F_3$ is the field of three elements.  You've got $(1,0) = 2(1,0)(2,2)(1,0)$. Does it look like $2(1,0)(2,2)=(1,1)$ to you?  The reason it doesn't work is because there's no reason to believe you can cancel $r$.